# rlist: recursively filter out list nodes with NA

Tags: r

Using (preferably) `rlist` package, is there a way to filter out nodes of the (multi-level) list, so that the resulting list holds no `NA` values on any level?

```
library(rlist)
devs <- 
  list(
    p1=list(name="Ken",age=24,
      interest=c("reading","music","movies"),
      lang=list(r=NA,csharp=4)),                      # <------ NA here
    p2=list(name="James",age=25,
      interest=c("sports","music"),
      lang=list(r=3,java=2,cpp=5)),
    p3=list(name="Penny",age=NA,                      # <------ NA here
      interest=c("movies","reading"),
      lang=list(r=1,cpp=4,python=2)))
```

In the above example, since `p1` and `p3` nodes contain `NA` somewhere in their hierarchy, the expected output list should be `p2` only. We don't know in advance the structure or names of the input list.

Comment: `rlist` tag doesn't yet exist, can someone with high enough reputation create it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.search()` scans the list recursively on a condition and can be used to find `NA`s in child elements of `devs`.

Using `pipeR` and `rlist` together to make the code clearer:

```
devs %>>% 
  list.filter(. %>>% 
      list.search(anyNA(.)) %>>% 
      length == 0L)
```

This singles out `p2` only.

This is almost a direct translation of your request :)

or an easier way is

```
list.filter(devs, !anyNA(unlist(.)))
```

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
# for every element in devs, does it have 0 NA elements when unlisted?
sapply(devs, function(x) !anyNA(unlist(x)))
```

which returns:

```
p1    p2   p3 
FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

You can get just the desired list element(s) with:

```
devs[sapply(devs, function(x) !anyNA(unlist(x)))]
```