# Filter list in R base on criteria within list objects

Tags: r, list, filter, tidyverse

This is a trivial question, but I'm stumped. How can I filter a list of dataframes based on their length? The list is nested -- meaning there are lists of lists of dataframes of different lengths. Here is an example. I'd like to filter or subset the list to include only those objects that are length *n*, say 3.

Here is an example and my current approach.

```
library(tidyverse)

# list of list with arbitrary lengths 

star.wars_ls <- list(starwars[1:5], 
                     list(starwars[1:8], starwars[4:6]), 
                     starwars[1:2], 
                     list(starwars[1:7], starwars[2:6]), 
                     starwars[1:3])


# I want to filter the list by dataframes that are 3 variables long (i.e. length(df == 3).

# Here is my attempt, I'm stuck at how to obtain 
# the number of varibles in each dataframe and then filter by it. 

map(star.wars_ls, function(x){
    map(x, function(x){ ## Incorrectly returns 20 for all 
        length(y)
    })

})
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the nesting? Unnest? Ignore? Hierarchically apply the filter?

Comment: I'd like to keep the nesting when applicable. So I suppose it'd be best to hierarchically apply a filter.

Comment: I'll edit that now. Thanks.

Comment: Mmm, I think "recursive filtering" might be a better term than "hierarchical filtering". [This looks promising](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26363145/903061)

Comment: I think you also need to edit to (a) define `n` and (b) define `y`. It'd be nice to see an expected result. Like, if `n` is 3, do you want `list(NULL, list(NULL, starwars[4:6]), list(NULL, NULL), starwars[1:3])`? Or something else?

Comment: I've updated to include n = 3, not sure how to proceed with defining y as my code above doesn't yet work in delivering the correct length of each dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
  map(star.wars_ls, ~ if(is.data.frame(.x)) .x[length(.x) == 3] else map(.x, ~ .x[length(.x) == 3]))
```

Comment: This solution doesn't actually filter/subset the list though, right? Looks like you're just dropping all columns  if the length is not 3, but the original list structure is still the same (just that you've mutated all the dataframes' contents).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check whether the item in the `star.wars_ls` is a list or a data frame. Then, check the number of columns within each item. Try using:

```
library(tidyverse)

# list of list with arbitrary lengths 

star.wars_ls <- list(starwars[1:5], 
                     list(starwars[1:8], starwars[4:6]), 
                     starwars[1:2], 
                     list(starwars[1:7], starwars[2:6]), 
                     starwars[1:3])


# I want to filter the list by dataframes that are 3 variables long (i.e. length(df == 3).

datacols <- map(star.wars_ls, function(X) {
  if (is.data.frame(X) == T) {
    ncol(X) } 
    else {
      map(X, function(Y) {
        ncol(Y)
      })
      }
    }
)

# > datacols
# [[1]]
# [1] 5
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] 8
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] 3
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[4]]
# [[4]][[1]]
# [1] 7
# 
# [[4]][[2]]
# [1] 5
# 
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 3
```

This will only give you the length (number of columns) of each data frame within the list. To get the indices (I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this -- maybe someone else can help with that):

```
indexlist <- c()
for (i in 1:length(datacols)) {
  if (length(datacols[[i]]) == 1) {
    if (datacols[[i]][1] == 3) {
      index <- i 
      indexlist <- c(indexlist, as.character(index))
    }
  } else {
    for (j in 1:length(datacols[[i]])) {
      if (datacols[[i]][[j]][1] == 3) {
        index <- str_c(i, ",", j)
        indexlist <- c(indexlist, index)
      }
    }
  }
}

# > indexlist
# [1] "2,2" "5"
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use recursion. It doesnt matter how deeply nested the list is:

```
ff = function(x)map(x,~if(is.data.frame(.x)){if(length(.x)==3) .x} else ff(.x))
ff(star.wars_ls)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned subset/filter, you could use `Reduce` from base R with recursion to produce your subset:

```
my_reduce = function(x) {
  Reduce(function(acc, b) {
    if (is.data.frame(b)) {
      # could transform before appending b as well
      if (length(b) == 3) append(acc, list(b)) else acc
    } else {
      append(acc, my_reduce(b))
    }
  }, x, list())
}

my_reduce(star.wars_ls)
```

Or you could flatten your list first with the help of `purrr` since 1.0.0 and filter then (although it wouldn't handle more than one level of nesting):

```
tibble(x = star.wars_ls %>% list_flatten()) %>% 
  filter(map_lgl(x, ~ length(.x) == 3))
```